# How to fix "We couldn’t deliver this payload: Couldn't connect to server" in github webhook while setting up a jenkins trigger?

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-blueocean, kitematic, git-webhooks

I'm setting up a Web-hook in GitHub to trigger a Jenkins build for every push event. I'm running Jenkins from a Blue Ocean Docker container.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/10HRD.jpg

I'm able to access jenkins from http://192.168.99.101:32771/ , as specified in the docker container.
I have specified the git repository and checked "GitHub hook trigger for GITScm polling" checkbox.

I am able to manually kick off the build process after a commit, but when I setup the webhook in github with the payload url http://192.168.99.101:32771/github-webhook/ and commit something, 
I get the error "We couldn’t deliver this payload: Couldn't connect to server"

Other solutions I've looked at.

1. Using ngrok. But I'm not running this on localhost.
2. I tried using a Personal Access Token and created an automatic webhook from Jenkins to Github. And I got the same error.

What am I missing, or what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Github will never reach to your **Jenkins Server** as your server is only accessible with-in network.

The error is very clear.

> We couldn’t deliver this payload: Couldn't connect to server

`http://192.168.99.101:32771` this is the same as your local host in term of access it from outside of the network.

Possible solution.

- Run jenkins on some remote server with Internet access and give that IP in the webhook of the Github
- Pass your [public IP](https://whatismyipaddress.com/) to Github, maybe you still issue with define [port forwarding](https://portforward.com/) if there is any issue with access.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That really clarified things for me.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who's jenkins server is in a Ec2 instance of AWS and if it is in a private subnet, you can do two things:

1. Move your private ec2 into a public subnent
2. Create a Load balancer (ALB) within a public subnet and attach your private ec2 instance to that Load Balancer. Then use the address of ALB for you github hook.